# Huge Amount of Linker Issues with Release Build Only

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, linker-errors, glut

Anyone have idea on this? Linker errors are way out of my wheelhouse, especially ones like this.

Is there any more info I should include?

```
1>Linking...
1>freeglut_static.lib(freeglut_window.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __heap_alloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(malloc.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __recalloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(recalloc.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __msize already defined in LIBCMT.lib(msize.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(malloc.obj) : error LNK2005: _V6_HeapAlloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(malloc.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in LIBCMT.lib(dbghook.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: ___sbh_pHeaderDefer already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __get_sbh_threshold already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __set_sbh_threshold already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __set_amblksiz already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __get_amblksiz already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: ___sbh_heap_init already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: ___sbh_find_block already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: ___sbh_free_block already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: ___sbh_alloc_block already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: ___sbh_alloc_new_region already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: ___sbh_alloc_new_group already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: ___sbh_resize_block already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: ___sbh_heapmin already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: ___sbh_heap_check already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(isctype.obj) : error LNK2005: __isctype_l already defined in LIBCMT.lib(isctype.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(isctype.obj) : error LNK2005: __isctype already defined in LIBCMT.lib(isctype.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be linking projects built with different CRT library settings, one with Multi-Threaded, another one with Multi-Threaded Debug.  Adjust the settings for *all* the projects to use the very same flavour of the library and the issue should go away!

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't normally try and pull in LIBCMTD in a release build, it's the debug version of LIBCMT.

It seems that your release build is trying to link to something that was built debug. You probably have a broken dependency in your build, (or you missed rebuilding something to release by hand if your project is normally built in pieces).

It would seem likely that it's the freeglut_static.lib that wasn't rebuilt for retail. If that isn't it then try deleting *all* of your build products (*.obj, *.lib, *.pch, *.pdb) of course being careful to *not* delete things that you don't produce - third party libs, etc.  Then build *just* release.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other remarks: Don't use "Edit and Continue" `/EDITANDCONTINUE` in release builds. That's a useful feature while debugging, as it can reduce rebuild times. But it does so by packing your executable in a non-optimized form.

You get the warning because the /OPT:ICF option will fold identical function bodies. This means two functions share the same address. Obviously this means you cannot edit & replace only one of them.